# Why is typescript complaining when trying to use ref in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, use-ref

I am using ref to animate elements on scroll.

```
  const foo = () => {
    if (!ref.current) return;
    const rect = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    setAnimClass(
      rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= window.innerHeight ? styles.animClass : ""
    );
  };
```

This code worked well in next.js app, but when I am using this in `create-react-app` type-script template, it is complaining that `Object is possibly 'null'.`

From `if (!ref.current) return;` it is clear that program will be returned if ref.current does not exist. But still, TypeScript gives error on the next line `ref.current.getBoundingClientRect()`, pointing at the `ref`.

How do I solve this issue without removing the null checking from typescript config?

complete file - https://github.com/mayank1513/react-contact-app/blob/master/src/components/ContactListItem.tsx

This is the complete project repo - https://github.com/mayank1513/react-contact-app

As of now, I have bypassed the issue using `"strict": false` in tsconfig. But I need to do it in strict mode.

Similar issue in [this file](https://github.com/mayank1513/react-contact-app/blob/master/src/pages/index.tsx) as well. And this is not resolved even by setting `"strict": false` in tsconfig. For now, I am just relying on `document.getElementById()` -- around line 65

Comment: Optional chaining might suppress the error `ref?.current?.getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: Try to this. `ref?.current!.getBoundingClientRect()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can cast ref to any as you get it from react.
`const ref = useRef(null) as any;`

Edit: I wanted to come back and give a more strongly typed solution, but Sakshi's answer does just that. This is the lazy fix, so follow their solution.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
const ref = useRef() as RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;

const foo = () => {
    if (!ref.current) return;
    const rect = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    setAnimClass(
      rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= window.innerHeight ? styles.animClass : ""
    );
  };
```

Comment: What is RefObject here? typescript complaining about RefObject

Comment: You also have to add an import statement.Add this `import { RefObject } from "react";`

Comment: this issue is resolved by I get error when using ref={ref} in jsx. Using useRef() as any works great, but I think this is more appropriate approach if jsx also works well

Comment: show me your code where are you using your `ref` ?

Comment: Link in the question itself

Comment: Hi, was a silly mistake. I was using the ref in input type. Solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

This is simple just add type `HTMLDivElement` to `useRef`, and the error didn't show up anymore:

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

**Bonus:** you should always remove the listener inside `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  foo();
  window.addEventListener("scroll", foo);
  window.addEventListener("resize", foo);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", foo);
    window.removeEventListener("resize", foo);
  }
}, []);
```